# jquery ajax async false causes click event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that runs through a multi-level array and each time calls a new ajax GET command to a php file with part of that array as the data.
Pretty basic...

```
for(var x=0; x<cities.length; x++){
    for(var u=0; u<links.length; u++){
       $.ajax({
                    url: "dontneedtoknow.php?city=" + cities[x] + "&link=" + links[u],
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 30000,
                    error: function(){
                        return true;
                    },
                    success: function(data){ 
                          //just appending data to page
                    }
                });
   }
}
```

I'd like to be able to have click() events and the ability to STOP this for loop but when this loop is going I can't do ANYTHING because of the async false.

I need the async false because I want the data to be appended as each function completes for a reason.

I have tried .live() but that doesn't seem to work...

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `async` is `false`, **the entire browser*** will be hung. You **cannot do anything** during a synchronous Ajax call other than waiting for the call to finish.

If you want to be able to stop the loop, you must use asynchronous calls.

See also:

- [What does "async: false" do in jQuery.ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/)
- [IE7 hangs when using (to much) ajax calls with async: false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141396/)
- [How to make all AJAX calls sequential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151598/)

That last link especially might be useful (if I understand what you're trying to accomplish here).

---

*unless you're in Chrome (then it's just the current page)

Comment: is there a way to generate the same sort of effect with asynchronous calls?

I am going through and pulling data from each city in my database and want it displayed in order...

Otherwise it just randomly dumps it as it finishes...

Comment: @mkprogramming: yup! see the edit I just made (the last link).

Answer (score 0):

Why make that many calls to the server? That seems very inefficient to me.

Is there a reason you can not change the service you are calling to receive a list of items and return it? It would involve one Ajax call and the server side code can make sure the data is processed in order.