# jQuery ajax does not work in production on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery

I am trying to make a service call using jQuery's ajax function. I have tested it on my local environment in both IE and Chrome and it works fine. However after deploying our site to production, I can only get the service call to work in Chrome. Stepping through the code in the inspector I can see that it makes it into the ajax function in IE but the the request is never issued. I have used fiddler and can see the call when using Chrome but not IE.

```
var customers;

function AutoComplete(TheId) {

    if (!customers) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "api/customerapi",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                customers = data;
            }
        });
     }

.... further code ....
}
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Why are you setting async to false?

Comment: Do you really need async: false?

Comment: Do you use a [document ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29) function? $(document).ready(function() { // do something -> AutoComplete call }); Please notice that you block your application with `async : false`.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in IE?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141396/ie7-hangs-when-using-to-much-ajax-calls-with-async-false

Comment: I am aware of blocking my application with `async : false`. In this case I need that data before the user can continue. And yes, I have checked for document loading issues.

Comment: @ferics2, why not use `async:true` and use a loading animation?

Comment: Dom was faster, but he's right. Use a loading animation instead of `async:false`.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who jumped on the async issue. That was the problem, I will just have to rework my logic to better use the success callback to ensure the correct order of operations I was going after. @Maetschl your link really led me to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There not a hole lot to go on from your code. You should provide more details and the link to the fiddle you made.

A few general things to consider:

Are you making https:// requests with http:// or vice-versa? This gave me trouble when working with IE after deploying to production (which was https). It would complain that security was being breached and wouldn't even make the request.

Also don't use `async: false` unless you have a **really** good reason to. It freezes the user's browser until the request is finished. On IE it's particularly bad because it freezes the entire browser, not only the page. There's hardly a reason you should use synchronous requests, since jQuery makes it so easy to just use the async. You can do the exact same thing that the sync does, without freezing the browser. Collect all the data needed then proceed from there. If your question is how to use the async request, I advise re-writing the question.

These are some very general suggestions, if you make your question more specific, you'll probably get an equally specific answer.