# jQuery ajax calling method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've wrote the following function so I don't need to rewrite ajax calls for every event I have.

```
function ajaxCall(){
        var params = new Array();

        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ){
            params[i] = arguments[i];
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: params[0],
            type: params[1],
            data: params[2],
            dataType : "json",
            beforeSend: function(x) {
                if(x && x.overrideMimeType){
                    x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Since ajax is asynchronous I cannot simply return the result from the ajaxCall function when call is successful. How can I create a success call back function? I've tried out this but it's probably wrong. Please help me on since I'm new to jquery & javascript.

```
ajaxCall("/getItemGroups", "POST" , data).success(function(){
            alert("success");
        });
```

Comment: use `success:callback` in ajax call and send a function as 4 argument when callin the ajacCall

Comment: at least see the api before asking question..

Comment: the ajax call returns a promise: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that motivates grabbing the `arguments` collection manually. Use named parameters:

```
function ajaxCall(url, type, data, callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        dataType : "json",
        success: callback,
        beforeSend: function(x) {
            if(x && x.overrideMimeType){
                x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Invoked like so:

```
ajaxCall("/getItemGroups", "POST", data, function() {
    alert('success');
});
```

I must say, though, that the resulting function adds very little to what `$.ajax` does manually. You may be more interested in looking at `$.ajaxSetup` to define a global `beforeSend` callback, for instance.

Anywhere in your code, call

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataType : "json",
    beforeSend: function(x) {
        if(x && x.overrideMimeType){
            x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        }
    }
});
```

Then your

```
ajaxCall('/getItemGroups', 'POST', data, function() { ... });
```

Would be identical to

```
$.post('/getItemGroups', data, function() { ... });
```

(There is of course a `$.get` equivalent)

Comment: Your answer is awesome! but one question though! say I have a place where I don't need any data to be passed. So how can when I write the function with 3 params, there will be an error! ho can I bypass this issue!

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri: JavaScript isn't picky about parameters. You can name two parameters and still call the function passing four, and you'll be able to access the others from the `arguments` collection, or conversely, you can have the `ajaxCall` signature that I outline above, but call it passing only three parameters, and `callback` will be `undefined`, meaning you'll call `$.ajax` setting `success: undefined`, which is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

The `jQuery.ajax()` function returns a [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), which your `ajaxCall` function can return. Then you can use the Deferred object's [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) function to add a success callback function to it.

```
function ajaxCall() {
    ...

    return $.ajax({
        // options
    });
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
ajaxCall(arguments).done(function(data) {
    // your logic here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `success` option:

```
   $.ajax({
            url: params[0],
            type: params[1],
            data: params[2],
            dataType : "json",
            success: function(data) { alert(data); },
            beforeSend: function(x) {
                if(x && x.overrideMimeType){
                    x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                }
            }
        });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
  function AJAXCall(successFunction) {
       $.ajax({
                url: params[0],
                type: params[1],
                data: params[2],
                dataType : "json",
                success: successFunction,
                beforeSend: function(x) {
                    if(x && x.overrideMimeType){
                        x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                    }
                }
            });
  }
```

Comment: I could simply do that if the success function doesn't change from call to call, but in my case, the success code changes with the call!

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri - pass the callback as a function

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
AjaxGET = function (myUrl, myData) {
    var result = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: myUrl,
        data: myData,
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
        }
    }) .responseText ;
return  result;
}
```

var myAjaxResponce = AjaxGet(myUrl, myData);

Comment: @anoooooooooooooooop if you have a single call, its perfect. You need to check if your ajax call returns or not any kind of data. I used it after user interactoin with my page. Explain why its bad practice.

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141396/ie7-hangs-when-using-to-much-ajax-calls-with-async-false

Comment: @anoooooooooooooooop i say it again, single call, not multiple calls. Call is made after user interction, NOT during page loading.